# Convert 8 bit Parallel output from ULN2003 to serial without any Microcontroller

Tags: shift-register, darlington, uln2003

I am hobbyist only with some basic idea about electronics..

I am trying to measure rooftop watertank water level and to display it on a small led bargraph. So by googling I thought about to proceed with ULN2003 darlington array.

Here is the circuit I'm trying.
[image]

But my challenge is it's little far from tank to the bargraph at room. So taking 7 wires from rooftop is not sounds to be a good approach. Is there is any encoders or something like that to convert this 8 output (in my case 6) to a single serial output and to decode it?

I thought about shift registers but it does require some mcu to control it and also some voltage restrictions.

So which is the best way.

I have one more confusion, which is the best metal to use as an underwater probe. Or how can I eliminate the risk of corrosion or oxidation issue after some period.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest 'no MCU' solution would be analogue.

Have an octal (or hex as you only want 6 electrodes) buffer at the tank, either the ULN2003, or perhaps better still a CMOS type like an HC7404, with a simple resistor to rail at the outputs. As each output goes valid, it draws more current from the rail.

The receiving end uses a current monitor resistor and a bargraph voltage measurement IC (like an [LM3914](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM3914)) to monitor the current drawn.

The advantage of CMOS is that you can use very low currents at your tank probes to minimize electrolytic corrosion, perhaps 1 MΩ resistors, or more.

I'd tend to use stainless steel as an electrode material, relatively inert, and cheap to replace when they finally rot.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest two-wire way Would be to use somerthing like LM3914
which is a chip that converts a voltage level into a bar-graph

on the tank you'd have a bunch of resistors dipping in the water pulling the voltage upwards and have pull down resistor or current sink to set the empty voltage.

kind-of like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEBTpq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>